Is their a way to create a \foreach loop with pylatex?
Sorry for the lack of description of my issue.
I would try to explain it.
I want to make a TikZ script that draws a curve in space.
At first, I thought I could use the symbolic expressions of the curve by making a LaTeX command with a parameter: t. I could do it along the 3 axis. And evaluate it along a list of t values by a \foreach loop. This would have looked like this:
\newcommand{\X}[#1]{X expression with #1 as the variable}
\newcommand{\Y}[#1]{Y expression with #1 as the variable}
\newcommand{\Z}[#1]{Z expression with #1 as the variable}

\newcommand{\Xprime}[#1]{Xprime expression with #1 as the variable}
\newcommand{\Yprime}[#1]{Yprime expression with #1 as the variable}
\newcommand{\Zprime}[#1]{Zprime expression with #1 as the variable}

\newcommand{\dt}{0.1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \t in {1, ..., n} {
        \draw (\X{\t},Y{\t},Z{\t}) -- ++(Xprime{\t}*\dt,Yprime{\t}*\dt,Zprime{\t}*\dt);
        
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

I would like this to be automated by a Python script that can compute (thanks to SymPy) symbolic differentiation to insert it in \newcommand{}{} LaTeX's macros definition.
This is why I need PyLaTeX to generate a foreach loop.
WORK-AROUND
Because I see many other potential issues from this kind of implementation I'll certainly generate each \draw line with PyLaTeX with numerical values coordinates computed by the Python.
SO NEW ISSUE I HAVE NOT YET LOOK INTO
Is PyLaTeX able to deal with 3D coordinates?
THANKS!

what is paylatex?  did you mean pylatex (as you have tagged) in which case you can use any normal latex package that defines this (pgffor for example)

if you need a loop in a tikz picture, use pgffor and not pylatex

No, that title is not self-explained.  What type of input are you wanting?  What type of output?  Are you wanting a for loop in Python to do something in TeX?  Or are you wanting Python to produce a \for loop in TeX?
